# Regex for Github Repository

Tags: regex, github, repository

i need a regular expression for links from github repositories.

Does anyone know how something like this could look like?

Answer (score 0):

This accepts links to the main page of any Github repository:

```
^https:\/\/github\.com(?:\/[^\s\/]+){2}$
```